# Pass variables to ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible

I need to pull a build from S3 on my target machine. Therefore I need to pass the S3 key and secret to the ansible playbook somehow.

I know that I could define them in

- the inventory
- the playbook itself

but I really don't want to store credentials there.

Can I use environment variables from the local machine (or something similar) in an ansible playbook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$ENV(SOMEVAR)` or `{{ lookup('env', 'SOMEVAR') }}` (1.1+) should work. You could also use `vars_prompt` to request it at playbook runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ansible-vault](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html)  it allows you to encrypt variables into a file and then "unlock" that file at run-time.

Failing that, you can also specify extra variables at runtime with the -e "" flag:

> ```
> ansible-playbook -i inv/production myplaybook.yml -e "s3_key=<value here> s3_secret=<secret here>"
> ```